# Add attribute data on my order page

Tags: attributes, frontend

On my account -> my order, there is order detail page and there are price, qty, subtotal column [image]

I wand to add other attribute data like 'brand' attribute

I found on items.phtml

```
<tr>
            <th style="width:55%" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>

            <th style="width:10%" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
            <th style="width:10%" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <th style="width:15%" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
        </tr>
```

I can add th style on the file but I have no idea how to load the attribute data

Comment: Normally there is a renderer phtml in a subfolder (I don't know the name by heart, have no Magento code here). If your attribute is passed trough quote and order object, it should be sufficient to add a column there and get your brand from the order object.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code , it works for me,
Add the code in,
app\design\frontend\theme\package\template\sales\order\items.phtml

```
<th><?php echo $this->__('Product') ?></th>
<th><?php echo $this->__('SKU') ?></th>
<th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Brand') ?></th>
<th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
<th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
<th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
```

app\design\frontend\theme\package\template\sales\order\items\renderer\default.phtml

Add `<td>` after sku

If the brand field in order table,

```
<td data-rwd-label="<?php echo $this->__('Brand') ?>"><?php echo $this->getOrder()->getBrandName() ?></td>
```

If it is in order item table

```
<td data-rwd-label="<?php echo $this->__('Brand') ?>"><?php echo $this->getOrderItem()->getBrandName() ?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you save `each order item` respective brand data in `sales_order_item` table in a column,

then you can get `brand name` using below code:

```
$_item->getBrandName();
```

If  not save then you need load the product model `(Mage::getModel('catalog'))` by order item `product id`.

**By like this:**

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());

if($product->getId()):

echo $product->getBrandFieldName()
endif;
```